# Arduino and Color LCD Shield

Tags: arduino

I am new at Arduino and I have two questions...
I found nothing on the internet about my problems:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Serial.println("Test: " + i);
}
```

The output:

```
test:
est:
st:
```

Second problem:
I am using LiquidCrystal to show a text on the display.
It's a Sparkfun Color LCD Shield.

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /* NOT WORKING 
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.print("Hello World!");
  */
```

}

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first** problem is due to the fact that `"Test: " + i` is handled with *pointer arithmetic*, as opposed to *string concatenation* which is what you *clearly* have in mind. Either write `Serial.print("Test: "); Serial.println(i);`, use proper [String objects](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) with a *[concatenation operator](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator)* or use `sprintf`.

The **second** problem is likely caused by the fact that your *lcd* uses the library `ColorLCDShield.h` instead of the `LiquidCrystal.h`, and thus is handled differently than cheaper and more common displays.
I suggest you to lookup the **documentation** specific for your **Sparkfun ColorLCD** model at their [website](https://www.sparkfun.com), they usually provide several *code examples* for their components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I installed the ColorLCDShield Library and read some docs.

But the library gives me some errors:

Comment: /Users/praktikant/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SparkFun_Color_LCD_Shield_Arduino_Library-V_1.0/SparkFunColorLCDShield.h:352:80: warning: narrowing conversion of '220' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

Comment: That's a *warning*, not an *error*. And it's definitively an issue from a programming point of view, since a `char` in *Arduino* is *signed* and can thus store values in `-128, 127` only. Without reading the source code I cannot give you a definitive answer, but it might be not harmful.